# Is that possible to create a web service in WCF for updating status in Facebook?

Tags: c#, facebook, web-services, wcf

I am creating a Web Service in WCF for Windows Phone application in which if the user logs in Facebook through Windows phone app the app will invoke the web service for updating the status through the app/session details passed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood is, you have a Windows phone app, if the user is logged into facebook with this app, the status should automatically update in the facebook. if this is the requirement why do you need the wcf service, you can directly consume the Facebook graph API in your app and update the status. I believe wcf service is not required in this case, Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: actually this is this is the required case...we need an app in Facebook by which user will log on and rest of the part will be handled by the WCF web service. Is there any way we can do it??